# Can't access form.valid in angular bootstrap js

Tags: angularjs

I have form  inside a angular bootstrap accordion.

like below.

```
 <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <accordion-group is-open="status.open">

       <ng-form name="createAssetForm" onsubmit="" novalidate class="form-horizontal">                    
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="AssetName">AssetName</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <div class="error error-msg" ng-show="(createAssetForm.AssetName.$dirty && createAssetForm.AssetName.$invalid && (!createAssetForm.AssetName.$focused))">
                                    <small class="error"
                                           ng-show="createAssetForm.AssetName.$error.minlength">
                                        Project name is required to be at
                                        least 3 characters
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="error" ng-show="createAssetForm.AssetName.$error.maxlength">
                                        Project name cannot be longer than
                                        250 characters
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                <input ng-focus ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="250" name="AssetName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Asset Name" ng-model="NewAsset.AssetName" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
 </ng-form>

        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

In my controller, i can't access

```
$scope.createAssetForm.$valid
```

Route for this page is

```
 .state('manageasset', {
        url: '/userstories/projects/:projectid/asset',
        templateUrl: '/app/userstories/assets/views/assetHome.html',
        controller: 'US_assetController',
        resolve: {
            IsAuthenticated: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) {
                return AuthService.isAuthendicatedPromised();
            }]
        },
        data: {
            isAuthenticated: true
        }
    })
```

Please help me to find the issue!

Comment: Where is html/routing configuration is your controller declaration?

Comment: @sathishkumar what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure maybe is better option but you cann access it using $watch
please see example:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){

  
  $scope.$watch('createAssetForm.$valid', function(value){
    //value is your createAssetForm.$valid
    $scope.isValid = value
    
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
  
  Is form valid: {{isValid}}
    <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
            <accordion-group is-open="status.open">

       <ng-form name="createAssetForm" onsubmit="" novalidate class="form-horizontal" >                    
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="AssetName">AssetName</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <div class="error error-msg" ng-show="(createAssetForm.AssetName.$dirty && createAssetForm.AssetName.$invalid && (!createAssetForm.AssetName.$focused))">
                                    <small class="error"
                                           ng-show="createAssetForm.AssetName.$error.minlength">
                                        Project name is required to be at
                                        least 3 characters
                                    </small>
                                    <small class="error" ng-show="createAssetForm.AssetName.$error.maxlength">
                                        Project name cannot be longer than
                                        250 characters
                                    </small>
                                </div>
                                <input ng-focus ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="250" name="AssetName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Asset Name" ng-model="NewAsset.AssetName"  />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
 </ng-form>

        </accordion-group>
    </accordion>

      </div>
  </div>
```